# How can I add regex for this one?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add comma between Haircut and Wash. basically like this: `Haircut, Wash And Blow Dry`

```
 if(string === 'HaircutWashAndBlowDry'){
    string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    str = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim();
  }
```

Comment: basically like this: `if(string === 'HaircutWashAndBlowDry') str = "Haircut, Wash And BlowDry";` ..

Comment: json key is `HaircutWashAndBlowDry`.

Comment: That's why regex is needed at `Haircut, Wash`.

Comment: Try `'HaircutWashAndBlowDry'.replace(/^([A-Z][^A-Z]*)([A-Z])|([A-Z])/g, function($0,$1,$2,$3) {return $2 ? $1 + ", " + $2 : " " + $3 ;})`

Comment: Find `Wash`, Replace `', Wash '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to lowercase first letter. Use `\B` along with a simple counter:

```js
var str = 'HaircutWashAndBlowDry';
var i = 1;
console.log(str.replace(/\B([A-Z])/g, function(match, $1) {
    return ( i++ == 1 ? ', ' : ' ' ) + $1; 
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Funny goal :) Let's play a bit with two previous answers (testCase 2 & testCase 3) that relies on words positions and a wider approach that relies on splitting on the `And` string to behave differently :

```js
// Haircut, Wash And Blow Dry
let strings = [
  'HaircutWashAndBlowDry',
  'HaircutWashCleanAndBlowDrySet'
];

function testCase1(str) {
  let pieces = str.split('And');
  
  pieces[0] = pieces[0].replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1, $2');
  pieces[1] = pieces[1].replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
  return pieces[0] + ' And ' + pieces[1];
}

function testCase2(string) {
  return string.replace(/^([A-Z][^A-Z]*)([A-Z])|([A-Z])/g, function($0,$1,$2,$3) {return $2 ? $1 + ", " + $2 : " " + $3 ;});
}

function testCase3(str) {
  let i = 1;
  return str.replace(/\B([A-Z])/g, function(match, $1) {
    return ( i++ == 1 ? ', ' : ' ' ) + $1; 
  });
}

strings.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str);
  console.log('testCase1 : ' + testCase1(str));
  console.log('testCase2 : ' + testCase2(str));
  console.log('testCase3 : ' + testCase3(str));
});
```